# Pesquisa com filtro Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho uma um Select, e um campo de pesquisa, que busca tudo dentro de uma tabela.

```
<select class="custom-select col-12" id="selecionarOrgao">
   <option value="">Escolha o órgão</option>
    <option value="2">portaria</option>
    <option value="3">Vidraçaria</option>
</select>
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control input-search" placeholder="Digite aqui sua pesquisa." id="buscarServico" name="buscarServico" value="" type="text" />
</div>
```

Essa é minha tabela:

```
<table  id="servico" class="table table-hover table-click lista-servicos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Serviço</th>
            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
            <th class="" scope="col">Órgão</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr data-cod="3">
            <td>
               Vidro
            </td>
            <td>
               Concerto de porta de vidro
            </td>
            <td class="">
               Vidraçaria
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-cod="10">
            <td>
                Concerto de porta
            </td>
            <td>
              Concertar portas de todos os modelos, exceto porta de vidro
            </td>
            <td class="">
                Portaria
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tenho esses dois scripts, um é para fazer o filtro pela pesquisa, de acordo com o que o usuário digita, e o outro é para o select, buscar somente os resultados de acordo com o escolhido, no select, busco pelo código, que está no `data-cod` da `<tr>`.

Filtrar pela Pesquisa digitada:

```
<script>
var $rows = $('#servico tr');
$('#buscarServico').keyup(function () {
    var parametroDeBusca = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    parametroDeBusca = RemoverAcentos(parametroDeBusca);
    if (parametroDeBusca.length >= 3) {
        $rows.show().filter(function () {
            var textoDaLinhaDaTabela = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            textoDaLinhaDaTabela = RemoverAcentos(textoDaLinhaDaTabela);
            return !~textoDaLinhaDaTabela.indexOf(parametroDeBusca);
        }).hide();
    } else {
        $rows.show().filter(function () {
        }).show();
    }
});

function RemoverAcentos(textoDaLinha) {
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[áàãâä]/gi, "a");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[éèê]/gi, "e");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[íìïî]/gi, "i");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[óòöôõ]/gi, "o");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[úùüû]/gi, "u");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[ç]/gi, "c");
    textoDaLinha = textoDaLinha.replace(/[ñ]/gi, "n");

    return textoDaLinha.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, " ");
}
</script>
```

Selecionar de acordo com o orgão selecionado:

```
<script>
  var filterTable = function (item) {
      // Get the value of the select box
      var val = item.val();

      // Show all the rows
      $('tbody tr').show();

      // If there is a value hide all the rows except the ones with a data-cod of that value
      if (val) {
          $('tbody tr').not($('tbody tr[data-cod="' + val + '"]')).hide();
      }
  }


  $('select').on('change', function (e) {
      // On change fire function
      filterTable($(this));
  });

  // Fire function on load
  filterTable($('select'));
</script>
```

O problema é que do jeito que mostra ai, depois que eu seleciono o orgão, e faço uma pesquisa, ele me trás todos os resultado, mesmo os que não são do orgão que eu selecionei. ou seja, mesmo com a `<tr>` em hide, aparece nos resultados.
como eu faço, para fazer a busca de acordo com o que digito somente nos resultados do orgão selecionado???

Comment: Talvez não seja útil para vc, mais tem uma lib já que faz muitos dessas funcionalidades já pronta, a lib é [DataTable](https://datatables.net/). De uma olhada e vê se pode ti ajudar em algo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente asssim:
Adicione uma classe à todas as `<tr>`, para ser mais específico:

```
<tr data-cod="3" class="filter-rows">
  <td>
    Vidro
  </td>
  <td>
    Concerto de porta de vidro
  </td>
  <td>
    Vidraçaria
  </td>
</tr>
```

Altere sua função de filtro para fazer com que esconda tudo primeiro e depois só mostre o que você quer/precisa:

```
var filterTable = function (item) {
  var val = item.val();

  $('.filter-rows').hide();
  $('.fiter-rows [data-cod="' + val + '"]').show();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda assim, continua buscando tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Troque a função para:

```
function filterTable (item) {
    var val = item.val();

    $('.filter-rows').hide();
    $('.filter-rows[data-cod="'+val+'"]').show();
}
```

Testando e funcionando:
https://the-cyberpunk.com/exemplo/

Você também pode adicionar um if, para se a pessoa voltar para o "Escolha uma opção", ele mostrar tudo novamente:

```
function filterTable (item) {
    var val = item.val();

    if(val.length > 0) {
        $('.filter-rows').hide();
        $('.filter-rows[data-cod="'+val+'"]').show();
    } else {
        $('.filter-rows').show();
    }
}
```